# Does centering data destroy information if the data are not gaussian distributed?

Tags: variance, mean, dataset, normalization

I've alway wondered if you are given tabular data where things have different distributions (some features are normally distributed, some are log-normally distributed) if centering the data by...

$$
\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}
$$

Do we destroy the information about the variables which do not have a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your level of measurement is an interval scale, you can do positive linear transformations ($x' = ax+b$ with $a>0$) without losing information. This does not depend on the distribution of your data.

Note that for centering, you can set $a = \frac{1}{\sigma}$ and $b = \frac{\mu}{\sigma}$. Since $\sigma>0$, this will be a positive linear transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what qualifies as an "interval scale?"

Comment: When you can interpret the difference between values in a meaningful way. If you can compute mean and standard deviation, you should typically have an interval variable. You can find more information on levels of measurement for instance [here](https://medium.com/peter-flom-the-blog/nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio-stevens-typology-and-some-problems-with-it-93b1033815f7)